# Formula to Find Next Value in a Column that Contains a Certain Value in another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Current     Next             1  Apple
2           5                2  Boy
                             3  Cat
                             4  Apple
                             5  Boy
                             6  Cat
                             7  Apple
```

I have cell 1 that contains the value "2". I need a formula that would return the next value in a column that contains the value "oy" in another column. But it cant return the same value, has to return a value greater than the current. So next value greater than 2 that contains "OY" in another column.

Example should return the number 5.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I used OY as an example cause id be searching for partial values inside these cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to set the RANGE and another INDEX/MATCH to return the value:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,C:C,0)+1):C1040000,MATCH("*oy*",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0)+1):D1040000,0))
```

[image]

---

Avoid using OFFSET or INDIRECT as they are volatile functions.

Comment: I updated original post because I realize my actual data is more complex. it would need to have a greater than formula somehow.

Comment: This only works if you data is sorted on the numbers column my column C.  If it is not or cannot be sorted then you will need an array formula.  Let me know.